# Why is this lua gsub not working?

Tags: lua

I have some lua code that is part of a rest api.  I'm extending it to handle redirects.
However, I'm having trouble with a gsub.

```
msg=POST /v2/keys/message?recursive=true&value=hello%20world HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.17.8.101:4001
Content-Length: 0
Accept: */*, application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, text/plain
```

I want to replace

```
path = "blabla"
msg = msg:gsub("^%w* ([^\r\n]*)\r\n.*", path .. " HTTP/1.1")
```

So that the result is:

```
msg=POST blabla HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.17.8.101:4001
Content-Length: 0
Accept: */*, application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, text/plain
```

But everything I've tried didn't match and didn't replace.  I think I just fundamentally misunderstand how lua gsub and it's pattern matching works.  What's wrong with the gsub?

Comment: Are you sure your string has `\r\n` newlines in it?

Comment: Yes that's what comes back from the server.  The HTTP response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you are over-matching.

You don't need to match the entire string with your pattern. Just the bits you want to modify.

Is `msg=` part of the string or a variable assignment? I'm going to assume that's a variable assignment (especially given `msg = msg:gsub(...)`.

Given that try:

```
msg = msg:gsub("^(%w*%s*)([^%s]*)", "%1"..path)
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the regexp doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below. Note the use of `1` to do just one match.

> `msg = msg:gsub("(%s+)(%S+)(%s+)", "%1"..path.."%3",1)`